Assign strings in VBA
how to assign string in solidworks vba i want to assign material with different and me put it into the material section?
but this doesnt work
Sub Material()
    Dim swFeat As Feature
    Dim swpart As PartDoc
    Dim SWDISPM As DisplayDimension
    Dim swdim As Dimension
    
    Dim swmodel As ModelDoc2
    Set swpart = swmodel
    Dim MAT As String
     MAT_NAME = "Cast Alloy Steel"
    ' Set swdispdim = swFeat.GetFirstDisplayDimension
     'MATVAL = "UserForm2.MUT1"
    boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Unknown", "BROWSERITEM", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
    Part.ClearSelection2 True
    Part.SetMaterialPropertyName2 "Default", "C:/Program Files/SOLIDWORKS   `your  `your  `your text`text`text`Corp/SOLIDWORKS/lang/english/sldmaterials/SOLIDWORKS Materials.sldmat", "& MAT_NAME &"
    Part.ClearSelection2 True
    
    'Part.ClearSelection2 True
End Sub


So you get an error? Is your path in the line SetMaterialProperty2 correct? Try MAT_NAME instead "& MAT_NAME &" in this line.
